# Value of discriminant in inequality

Tags: inequality

Find $m\in \mathbb{R}$ so that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the inequality is true:
$$\left(m+2\right)e^{-2x}+2\left(m+2\right)e^{-x}+m>0$$

I tried substituting $e^{-x}$ with t, so that I'd have a second order linear inequality for which I could calculate a discriminant and solutions. I don't know if this helps me though, what value should I be looking for in the discriminant so that the inequality is always true? I know that $e^{-2x}$ will always be positive, hence why I did the substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want:
$$ (m+2)(e^{-x}+1)^2> 2 \tag{1}$$
hence it is enough to compute the infimum of $(e^{-x}+1)^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

It is trivially $1$, so $(1)$ holds for any $m\geq 0$.

Comment: You make it seem so simple. I understand how you re-wrote the inequality. Then you found the minimum value of $\left(e^{-x}+1\right)^{2}$ so you could see what value m should take so that the inequality is always positive, yes?

Comment: @MikhaelM: exactly.